# Does resource import order matters in Spring XML?

Tags: java, spring

Lets say I import four resource files in my application's main configuration file as below,

```
<import resource="db-config.xml"/>
<import resource="cache-config.xml"/>
<import resource="sec-config.xml"/>
<import resource="rajnikanth.xml"/>
<!-- My app beans here -->
```

My understanding is that Spring creates a DAG and instantiate bottom-up. What about the disconnected nodes in the graph? Does order of import come into the play? Please explain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, order matters. If you declare a bean in one imported file and then declare a bean with the same name in a subsequently imported file, the first bean declaration is overridden.

**UPDATE:** To more directly address your question, it is fine to have beans in earlier imports refer to beans in later imports. Order does not matter in this way.

Comment: Are you sure of this? In older Spring versions (3.x), defining same bean in two imported configs was an error AFAIK. What was allowed was to redefine a bean in your config overriding a bean from import.

Comment: I count on it working this way, and I use Spring 3.x. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5317688/2540382 for confirmation.